# Angularjs HTTP Request Header Not working from chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http-headers

I have a function for a Angularjs controller making a backend API call as below. This snippet works fine with IE but failing for Chrome - always going to error flow.

It works fine with Chrome if custom request Header is dropped from the request. Any clue why?
Note, server always sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *`

```
$scope.getProductsClick = function(item, event) {


    var responsePromise = 
        $http.get(basePath + "products?customerId=12345",
        {
            headers: {
                'myheader': 'xyz'
            }
        }
    );
    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.getProductsResponse = data.product;
        });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Get Prodcts Failed !!!");
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it may be because you need to add myheader to Access-Control-Allow-Headers on the server.